# Query M value where point intersects route in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

Is there a way I can query the M value along my route where a point touches the line. I'd like to use the field calculator in my Points fc to query the M value where the point intersects the line and populate the field with an M value. My points are M aware.

I've done something slightly similar by querying the beginning and end measure values from a line and applying it to a field in the line's table using !Shape.extent.MMin!.

Rather than manually inputting the measure value where the point and line intersect using the Route Identify tool, I'd like to automate this process if possible.

Comment: Are you looking for a manual approach, it's not clear what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Why did you delete your other question?  I think it may have been better to edit your original question with updated information rather than deleting it (and the comments/suggestions others had already made) and creating a new question.

Comment: @Midavalo My problem changed slightly and it was easier for me redo than edit. I will edit next time to save the others suggestions.

Comment: @Hornbydd I am trying to automate this as much as I can. My points intersect a line that has M values applied. I'd like to populate a field in my points table with the measure of the line where it intersects.

Comment: Please be aware that deleting content too often can flag you for vandalism and potentially could block you from posting more questions

Comment: Sounds like you need only run the _Locate Features Along Routes_ tool which is in the linear referencing toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Made sure points are snapped to line. Run Locate Routes Along Features tool. Join resulting table to original points feature class based on Input OID.